# Rotate label to right with 45 degree

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have this options at the chart:

```
options:{
    scales: {
        xAxis:{
            ticks: { maxRotation: 45, minRotation: 45 },
        }
    }
}
```

But is not really what I want. And I wanted with -45 and this is worst:

[image: tried]

What I really want is this:

[image: want]

It is possible to configure it like this?

Comment: Have you tried going in the other direction - `315` instead of `-45`?

Comment: @CBroe, yes, it looks like -45. I think the angle -45 can be good, but the problem becomes the positions/alignment. I don't really know and don't even know how to change it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure will it work for your scenario, but you can try this.

```
options:{
    scales: {
        xAxis:{
            ticks: {
                offset: true,
                padding: 20,
                labelOffset: 25,
                align: 'start',
                maxRotation: 315,
                minRotation: 315,
            },
        }
    }
}
```

You can increase or decrease `labelOffset` and `padding` properties according your need.

**Note** - Note: this can cause labels at the edges to be cropped by the edge of the `canvas`. For solving this issue, you can increase size of `canvas` tag and providing some `padding` inside canvas.

For Example -

```
options: {
    layout: {
        padding: 25, // in pixels
  }
}
```

If I'm not wrong, providing canvas `padding` equal to tick `labelOffset` would solve this cropping issue.

Comment: Thank you for help. It works, but no completely. It looks perfect on my laptop, but when I switch on other device with different resolution. It's no longer fits that good.

Comment: @KunLun if possible, could you generate a sharable code over any online code editor, maybe over codepen, it would be easy to assist you. Thanks!

Comment: Here is a link from codepen: https://codepen.io/raul1ro/pen/vYRgqjY?editors=0010 , these are my all settings for chart.

Comment: @KunLun Hey, I can see that you have not provided any dimension to `canvas` tag, is there any specific dimension that you want to set for `canvas` ?

Comment: The size is dynamic(based on the resolution). My entire page is with multiple charts. I am using bootstrap to position/size them. I have 2 charts with(col-6) per row.